# Android: Adding RecyclerView below Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a RecyclerView underneath a Fragment that I add programmatically, but it doesn't show up. I would like the RecyclerView to dynamically use the remaining space of the screen (since the Fragment above it can vary in size) so I put constraints at the edges and set the height to 0dp. The RecyclerView populates just fine, but it displays somewhere below the screen (I have to put the height of the RecyclerView to ~1300 dp to make it show up).

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Toolbar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/FragmentContainer"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I then use this code to programmatically add the Fragment to my FragmentContainer:
**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Remove current fragment(s)
        for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment!!).commit()
        }

        val transaction: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        var fragment: Fragment

        if (someBoolean)
            fragment = FirstFragment()
        else
            fragment = SecondFragment()

        // Add correct fragment to container
        transaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
}
```

I have tried putting the RecyclerView into various layouts, but the results weren't any better. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: The `RecyclerView` is being exactly displayed at the bottom of the `RelativeLayout` as defined in your xml which is correct. The problem is with the `RelativeLayout` because it does not have a bottom constraint.

Comment: I've connected the RelativeLayout's bottom constraint to the top of my RecyclerView to make a chain but that didn't help. I've also tried to add an empty ImageView between the RelativeLayout and the RecyclerView and chaining them together there, but my RecyclerView still goes beyond the bottom of the screen unless I put the height to a very high value.

Comment: FIXED : Both my fragments that go above my RecyclerView had a constraint layout with the height of "match_parent" instead of "wrap-content", thus causing my RecyclerView to be pushed off-screen.